# HTML/CSS - How to autofit/scale multiple images onto 1 row

Tags: html, css

I cut a flowchart drawn in Photoshop into various "parts" that I want to "reassemble" onto a webpage. All of the "parts" have the same height but different widths. To fully reassemble the flowchart, I'd need 4 rows and each row would have anywhere from 4 to 5 images. I would like the "flowchart" to automatically scale with the window size.

How would I do about doing this in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;`

```
<div class="images-row">
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
  <div><img src="" class="images"/></div>
</div>

 **style of CSS**
 .images-row{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}
 .images-row div{width:17%;padding:5px;}
 .images{ width:100%; height:150px;background:#ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `responsive`images for them to scale with the windows size:

`width: 100%; max-width: 400px; height: auto;`